# Calculate perturbed eigenvector components of sub-stochastic (PF) matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, perturbation-theory, nonnegative-matrices

I have a (column) sub-stochastic matrix, $P$, which is nonnegative and irreducible (hence satisfies the criteria of the Perron Frobenius theorem). I know its dominant eigenvalue, $\rho$ and left and right eigenvectors corresponding to $P$. That is, $P v = \rho v$ and $u^T P = \rho u^T$. Additionally I use the following normalizations: $\sum_i v_i = 1$ and $\sum_i u_i v_i = 1$.

Now, I perturb a single column of $P$ by a constant, encoded in matrix $E$.
Under consideration is the new eigenvalue equation: $(P+E)v' = \rho' v'$. (I assume that the perturbation is not too large so that $P+E$ still satisfies P.F. thm). Expanding, and writing $\rho' = \rho + \delta \rho$ and $v'=v+\delta v$;

\begin{equation}
Pv + P \delta v + Ev + E \delta v = \rho v + \rho \delta v + \delta \rho v + \delta \rho \delta v
\end{equation}

Removing second order terms, and using the original eigenvector equation, we have
\begin{equation}
P \delta v + Ev= \rho \delta v + \delta \rho v
\end{equation}
Dotting with $u^T$ on both sides and using normalization tells us
\begin{equation}
u^T P \delta v + u^T E v = \rho u^T \delta v + \delta \rho u^T  v
\end{equation}

or \begin{equation}
u^T E v = \delta \rho u^T  v
\end{equation}
which is great, as we now have a first order estimate of the perturbation of the Perron root; namely $\delta \rho = u^T E v.$

However, I am also interested in the first order perturbation to the entries of left and right eigenvectors $u, v$.

I do **not** know the other non-dominant eigenvectors (so I do not want to use them as a basis), but I am guessing we can return to the vector equation:

\begin{equation}
P \delta v + Ev= \rho \delta v + \delta \rho v
\end{equation}
which can be rewritten as
$(P - \rho \mathbf{1}) \delta v = (\delta \rho \mathbf{1}-E)v$, where the RHS is now a calculable vector.

How can I extract a first order perturbation for the entries of $\delta v$?

Extra things to keep in mind; $\sum_i \delta v_i = 0$, $u$ is normal to $\delta v$ in first order.
Also, I do not want to attempt to invert $P-\rho \mathbf{1}$, as it is usually non-invertible. I also do not want to use the generalized matrix inverse. Computations involving either of these are usually more difficult than simply calculating the new Perron vectors after all!

TIA for any help

P.S. - I am also especially interested in (simple) results for the derivative of $u$ and $v$ w.r.t. the matrix entries $P$. I have seen some results by Elsner, Neumann, Lu, etc. But most deal with the generalized matrix inverse.

Comment: Since the perturbation is small, try one or two steps of the [Power Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration)
$$w=(P+E)v,\quad \sigma=\sum_k w_k,\quad v_+=\frac 1\sigma w$$ starting at the known Perron vector.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the matrices $P$ are often so large that storage is already a problem, and even this computation takes some time. Will take a look at its convergence speed though, thanks.

Comment: Well, you already know that $Pv=\rho v,\,$ so you really only need to calculate $Ev.\,$ If $E\,$ has some special structure (or sparseness) then that could make the calculation feasible.

Comment: One step of the power iteration yields 
$$
v_+ \;=\; v+\delta v \;=\; \frac{\rho v + Ev}{\rho+{\tt1}^TEv}
$$

Comment: Aha! Nice, this might help.

Comment: @greg It was a good idea, but unfortunately it actually didn't help in the few cases I've tried. (the equation for $v_{+}$ is worse than $v$ itself for $v'$...